# jQuery UI Dialog Box - does not open after being closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a problem with the [`jquery-ui dialog box`](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

**The problem is that when I close the dialog box and then I click on the link that triggers it, it does not pop-up again unless I refresh the page.**

How can I call the dialog box back without refreshing the actual page.

Below is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showTerms').click(function()
    {
        $('#terms').css('display','inline');
        $('#terms').dialog({
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            width: 400,
            height: 450,
            overlay: { backgroundColor: "#000", opacity: 0.5 },
            buttons:{ "Close": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } },
            close: function(ev, ui) { $(this).remove(); },
    }); 
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I solved it.

I used destroy instead close function (it doesn't make any sense), but it worked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#showTerms').click(function()
{
    $('#terms').css('display','inline');
    $('#terms').dialog({resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 400,
        height: 450,
        overlay: { backgroundColor: "#000", opacity: 0.5 },
        buttons:{ "Close": function() { $(this).dialog('**destroy**'); } },
        close: function(ev, ui) { $(this).close(); },
    });         
});   
$('#form1 input#calendarTEST').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'MM d, yy' });
});
```

Comment: Destroy will work if you use that method, but to make close() work, instantiate the dialog first, then use dialog.show() to show it, then dialog.close() to close it, and it will reopen without a problem.

Comment: Almost. You're right about initilizing it first, but after that it's .dialog("open") and .dialog("close")

Answer (score 110):

You're actually supposed to use `$("#terms").dialog({ autoOpen: false });` to initialize it.
Then you can use `$('#terms').dialog('open');` to open the dialog, and `$('#terms').dialog('close');` to close it.

Comment: This works perfectly. The jQuery UI documents aren't very clear here. But the idea that `dialog` function is for initialization, showing, and hiding made sense of this for me. Thanks.

Comment: If you're loading this dialog from HTML that can dynamically change, it's very unintuitive why it doesn't work.  Anybody have any good solutions that can be applied generically to these situations?

Comment: @Milimetric You can always use the $(this).remove(); function at the end of each of your dialog's buttons, this way the whole dialog will be completely remade from scratch when you call it again. Note that this function acts differently than $(this).dialog("destroy"); since it only sets the dialog back to its pre-init state, without destroying the object.

Answer (score 12):

on the last line, don't use `$(this).remove()` use `$(this).hide()` instead.

EDIT: To clarify,on the close click event you're removing the `#terms` div from the DOM which is why its not coming back. You just need to hide it instead.

Answer (score 9):

I believe you can only initialize the dialog one time. The example above is trying to initialize the dialog every time #terms is clicked. This will cause problems. Instead, the initialization should occur outside of the click event. Your example should probably look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // dialog init
    $('#terms').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 400,
        height: 450,
        overlay: { backgroundColor: "#000", opacity: 0.5 },
        buttons: { "Close": function() { $(this).dialog('close'); } },
        close: function(ev, ui) { $(this).close(); }
    });
    // click event
    $('#showTerms').click(function(){
        $('#terms').dialog('open').css('display','inline');      
    });
    // date picker
    $('#form1 input#calendarTEST').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'MM d, yy' });
});
```

I'm thinking that once you clear that up, it should fix the 'open from link' issue you described.

Answer (score 3):

For me this approach works:

The dialog may be closed by clicking the X on the dialog or by clicking 'Bewaren'. I'm adding an (arbitrary) id because I need to be sure every bit of html added to the dom is removed afterwards.

```
$('<div id="dossier_edit_form_tmp_id">').html(data.form)
.data('dossier_id',dossier_id)
.dialog({
        title: 'Opdracht wijzigen',
        show: 'clip',
        hide: 'clip',
        minWidth: 520,
        width: 520,
        modal: true,
        buttons: { 'Bewaren': dossier_edit_form_opslaan },
        close: function(event, ui){ 
                                  $(this).dialog('destroy'); 
                                  $('#dossier_edit_form_tmp_id').remove();
               }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 <button onClick="abrirOpen()">Open Dialog</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
var $dialogo = $("<div></div>").html("Aqui tu contenido(here your content)").dialog({
       title: "Dialogo de UI",
       autoOpen: false,
       close: function(ev, ui){
               $(this).dialog("destroy");
       }
 function abrirOpen(){
       $dialogo.dialog("open");
 }
});

//**Esto funciona para mi... (this works for me)**
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a super old thread but since the answer even says "It doesn't make any sense", I thought I'd add the answer...

The original post used $(this).remove(); in the close handler, this would actually remove the dialog div from the DOM. Attempting to initialize a dialog again wouldn't work because the div was removed.

Using $(this).dialog('destroy') is calling the method destroy defined in the dialog object which does not remove it from the DOM.

From the documentation:

> destroy()
>
> > Removes the dialog functionality completely. This will return the element back to its >>pre-init state.
> >     This method does not accept any arguments.

That said, only destroy or remove on close if you have a good reason to.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).dialog('destroy');
```

works!

Answer (score 1):

.close() is mor general and can be used in reference to more objects.  .dialog('close') can only be used with dialogs

Answer (score 1):

I use the dialog as an dialog file browser and uploader then I rewrite the code like this

```
var dialog1 = $("#dialog").dialog({ 
              autoOpen: false, 
              height: 480, 
              width: 640 
}); 
$('#tikla').click(function() {  
    dialog1.load('./browser.php').dialog('open');
});
```

everything seems to work great.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with jquery-ui overlay dialog box - it would work only once and then stop unless i reload the page. I found the answer in one of their examples -
Multiple overlays on a same page
[flowplayer_tools_multiple_open_close](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/multiple.html)
 - who would have though, right?? :-) -

the important setting appeared to be

```
oneInstance: false
```

so, now i have it like this -

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 var overlays = null;

 overlays = jQuery("a[rel]");

 for (var n = 0; n < overlays.length; n++) {

    $(overlays[n]).overlay({
        oneInstance: false, 
        mask: '#669966',
        effect: 'apple',
        onBeforeLoad: function() {
            overlay_before_load(this);
        }
    });

  }

}
```

and everything works just fine

hope this helps somebody

O.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery documentation has a link to this article 
'[Basic usage of the jQuery UI dialog](http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/04/08/basic-usage-of-the-jquery-ui-dialog/)'
that explains this situation and how to resolve it.