# Strange Behavior of JQuery : multiple dialogs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html, jquery-jtable

I am facing a strange behavior of JQuery, I am sure it is related with JQuery not with jtable which I am using for whole of my implementation.

I have two columns for editing and deleting which I customized and replaced with jTabel default functionality. As soon as I click the edit button , The dailog appears for edit. I cancel and again click on any part of the jtabel's row, it again opens the same dialog which I opened before for editing the record. Moreover, If I click afterwards 'delete' button, it again opens the same dialog ( i.e edit ) dialog.

I have searched , people said to use $("dialog-form").dialog('destroy').remove(); it works, but after wards again I cannot interact with the edit dialog , as It's div is completely removed. I also tried only with $("dialog-form").destroy(''). It has totally weird behavior. Because of it, my Partial View is not rendered on JQuery Dialog which I am doing on it's "open" method, Instead it dispatches the whole HTML before jtable.

Moreover, I have observed strongly related issue, 
If I click delete first and then click edit, it opens previously delete form and pops up the edit form as well on each other.

Attached image (When Delete clicked after editing)

[image]

The edit dialog box opens even i clicked jtable's row and not clicking on the icon of delete on jtable's delete column.
[image]

This is my whole Code:

```
<div id="PersonTableContainer"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var rowID;
var retEditDialogDiv;

$("#dialogEdit-form").dialog(
    {
        autoOpen: false,
        title: "Edit Person",
        height: 380,
        width: 600,
        show: { effect: 'fold', direction: "up" },
        modal: true,

        open: function (event, ui) {
            var ID = rowID;
            $(this).load("Person/Edit", { a_id: rowID });
        },
        buttons:
        {
            "Cancel": function () {
                $("#dialogEdit-form").dialog('close');
            },

            "Save": function () {
                $("#update-message").html(''); //make sure there is nothing on the message before we continue

                $("#UpdatePersonForm").submit();
                $("#dialogEdit-form").dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
//}//end of ready
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#PersonTableContainer').jtable(
        {

            title: 'Person List',
            paging: true, //Enable paging
            sorting: true, //Enable sorting
            defaultSorting: 'Name ASC',
            selecting: true,
            addNewRecord: false,
            addRecordButton: false,
            showCloseButton: true,

            multiselect: true, //Allow multiple selecting
            selectingCheckboxes: true, //Show checkboxes on first column
            selectOnRowClick: false, //Enable this to only select using checkboxes

            actions:
            {
                listAction: '@Url.Action("GetPersons")'
            },
            toolbar:
            {
                hoverAnimation: true, //Enable/disable small animation on mouse hover to a toolbar item.
                hoverAnimationDuration: 60, //Duration of the hover animation.
                hoverAnimationEasing: undefined, //Easing of the hover animation. Uses jQuery's default animation ('swing') if set to undefined.

                items:
                [{
                    icon: '/Content/images/Misc/addRecordButton.png',
                    text: 'Add new record',

                    click: function () {
                        $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
                    }
                }]
            },
            fields:
            {
                PersonId:
                {
                    key: true,
                    create: false,
                    edit: false,
                    list: false
                },

                FirstName:
                {
                    title: 'First Name',
                    width: '15%',
                    sorting: true,
                    selecting: true,
                },
                LastName:
                {
                    title: 'Last Name',
                    width: '15%',
                    sorting: true,
                    selecting: true,
                },
                Email:
                {
                    title: 'Email Address',
                    width: '20%',
                    list: true,
                    sorting: true,
                    selecting: true,
                },
                DOB:
                {
                    title: 'DOB',
                    width: '15%',
                    type: 'date',
                    displayFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                    visibility: 'hidden',
                    list: false,
                    selecting: true
                },
                Title:
                {
                    title: 'Title',
                    width: '15%',
                    list: true,
                    sorting: true,
                    selecting: true,

                },
                Password:
                {
                    Password: 'Password',
                    width: '12%',
                    visibility: 'hidden',
                    list: false
                },
                Institute:
                {
                    title: 'Institute',
                    width: '10%',
                    create: true,
                    edit: true,
                    sorting: true,//This column is not sortable!
                    list: true,
                    selecting: true,
                },
                Roles:
                {

                    title: 'Role',
                    width: '10%',
                    options: '@Url.Action("GetRoles")',
                    defaultValue: 'Professors/User',
                    create: true,
                    edit: true,
                    sorting: true,//This column is not sortable!
                    list: true,
                    selecting: true,
                },
                Edit:
                {
                    title: '',
                    sorting: false,
                    edit: false,
                    create: false,
                    listClass: 'child-opener-image-column',
                    display: function (data) {
                        var $img = $('<img class="child-opener-image" src="/Content/images/Misc/editRecordButton.png" title="Edit record" />');

                        //Open EditPerson Dialog Box when user clicked Edit

                        $img.click(function () {
                            $('.jtable-data-row').click(function () {
                                rowID = $(this).attr('data-record-key');    
                                $("#dialogEdit-form").dialog("open");
                            });
                        });

                        return $img;
                    }
                },
                Delete:
                {
                    title: '',
                    sorting: false,
                    edit: false,
                    create: false,
                    listClass: 'child-opener-image-column',
                    display: function (data) {
                        var $img = $('<img class="child-opener-image" src="/Content/images/Misc/deleteRecord_Simple.png" title="Delete record" />');

                        //Open DeletePerson Dialog Box when user clicked Delete

                        $img.click(function () {
                            $('.jtable-data-row').click(function () {
                                rowID = $(this).attr('data-record-key');
                                $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
                            });
                        });

                        return $img;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    $('#PersonTableContainer').jtable('load');
    $('#PersonTableContainer').css("float", "left").width(1200).css('margin-left', '-20px');
});

$("#dialog-form").dialog(
    {
        autoOpen: false,
        title: "Create Person",
        height: 380,
        width: 600,
        show: { effect: 'fold', direction: "up" },
        modal: true,

        open: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).load("@Url.Action("Create")");
        },
        buttons:
        {
            "Cancel": function () {
                $("#dialog-form").dialog("close");
            },

            "Save": function () {
                $("#update-message").html(''); //make sure there is nothing on the message before we continue

                $("#createPersonForm").submit();
                $("#dialog-form").dialog('destroy');

            }
        }
    });
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog(
    {
        autoOpen: false,
        title: "Delete Person",
        height: 180,
        width: 380,
        show: { effect: 'fold', direction: "up" },
        modal: true,
        buttons:
        {
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog('destroy');
            },
            "Delete": function () {
                $("#update-message").html(''); //make sure there is nothing on the message before we continue
                $("#dialog-confirm").dialog('close');


                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Person/DeletePerson",
                    data: { PersonId: rowID },
                    success: PersonDeleted
                });
            }
        }
    });
function PersonDeleted(result) {
    $('.alert-box').html("Person Deleted");
    $('.alert-box').css("display:Block");
    $('.alert-box').css("float", "left").width(1130).css('margin-left', '-20px');
    $('.alert-box').delay(400).slideDown(400).delay(1000).slideUp(400);

    $('#PersonTableContainer').jtable('load');
}
</script>
```

If somebody faces the same issue and have resolved, or can help me out. I would be strongly obliged.

Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Usman

Answer (score 0):

I figure out myself. I applied hide() with close() in nested way. Moreover user88243's comments helped me out more. I applied return false immediately opening the dialog and it worked for me.

[Jquery Dialog - div disappears after initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272961/jquery-dialog-div-disappears-after-initialization)

Best Regards
Usman