# JQUERY UI Dialog not showing the div

Tags: jquery

Using the div divDialog for displaying the jquery UI Dialog box.  Dialog window pops up and display the message.  But I am not able to see the divsection divDialog in the html page at the end.  Thought Jquery UI dialog code is hiding it with display:none when dialog is initialized.  Tried many way to display it but nothing is working.  Pasted the code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://bbsmt01.dev.aapt.com.au:8080/testmanager/jquery/jquery-ui-themes-1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://bbsmt01.dev.aapt.com.au:8080/testmanager/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.3/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://bbsmt01.dev.aapt.com.au:8080/testmanager/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.3/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){

        $("#divDialog").dialog({
                resizable: true,
                autoOpen:false,
                show: {
                        effect: "blind",
                        duration: 1000
                },
                hide: {
                        effect: "explode",
                        duration: 1000
                },
                modal: true,
                width:400,
                height:300,
                buttons: {
                        ok: function() {
                                $(this).dialog('close');
                        } //end cancel button
                }//end buttons

        });//end dialog

               $("#divDialog").html("<b>test123</b>");
                $("#divDialog").dialog('option','title','Display Example');
                $('#divDialog').dialog('open');


});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p>Demonstrate JQUERY UI DIalog box.</p>
<br><br>
<div id="div1"  class="gen"  style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:red;"></div><br>
<div id="div2" class="gen"  style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:green;"></div><br>
<div id="div3" class="gen" style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:blue;"></div>
<div id="divDialog"  style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:blue;">testdivDialog</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why do you have 2 different version of jQuery? remove `jquery-ui-1.10.3/jquery-1.9.1.js`? and check

Comment: also check whether the files `http://bbsmt01.dev.aapt.com.au:8080/testmanager/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.3/jquery-1.9.1.js` exists

Comment: jquery dialog removes the div from it's location in the DOM when it opens/creates the dialog and places it within a different DIV for the dialog.  On dialog destroy, it returns the div back into it's original place in the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery dialog removes the div from it's location in the DOM when it opens/creates the dialog and places it within a different DIV for the dialog with class "ui-dialog". On dialog destroy, it returns the div back into it's original place in the DOM.  This link explains it better:

[Jquery Dialog - div disappears after initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272961/jquery-dialog-div-disappears-after-initialization)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 versions of jQuery in your page. If you want to use two or more versions of jQuery, you should use the jQuery `.noConflict()` method. Either way, check this simple dialog tutorial http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is your working code...

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z46rs/)**

Your div with id `divDialog` get removed when you popup it..

Create new div with different id

like..

```
<p>Demonstrate JQUERY UI DIalog box.</p>
<br><br>
<div id="div1"  class="gen"  style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:red;"></div><br>
<div id="div2" class="gen"  style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:green;"></div><br>
<div id="div3" class="gen" style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:blue;"></div>
    <br>
<div id="divDialog1"  style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:blue;">testdivDialog</div>

 <div id="divDialog"  style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:blue;"></div>
```

**Note**: please do not include same framework multiple times..