# jQuery popup dialog close after AJAX not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, razor, popup

I have found on the forum the same issues but cannot fix it anyway
I have a login form. Something like:

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("LogIn", "Account", null, new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "Post",
        UpdateTargetId = "result",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        LoadingElementId = "loginspinner",
        OnSuccess = "OnTryLogin"
    }, new { id = "loginform"}))
    {
        <div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { id = "loginusername"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
            </div>
..............................
```

I show popup (partialview) like:

```
$.get(loginaction, function (data) {
            var div;
            var divId = '#popupforlogin';
            div = $(divId);
            $(div).html(data);
            $(div).dialog({
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                autoOpen: false,
            });
            $(div).dialog('open');
            // ....
}
```

And I have:

```
function OnTryLogin(result) {
            if (result.success == true) {
                var fullPath = '@Url.Content("~/Account")' + '/LogOff';
                var userName = result.userName;
                $('#popupforlogin').dialog('close');
                //......
}
```

so the problem is that `dialog('close')` is not working.

Where am I mistaken?

Comment: *is not working* is not an explanation -- please add some kind of error message if you're getting any. If not, please let us know how you've tried to debug so far?

Comment: I mean dialog stays opened and I have no errors in the firebug console window. When I was debugging it went through a line "$('#popupforlogin').dialog('close');" without any errors

Answer (score 1):

You're actually supposed to use `$('#popupforlogin').dialog({ autoOpen: false });` to initialize it. Then you can use `$('#popupforlogin').dialog('open');` to open the dialog, and `$('#popupforlogin').dialog('close');` to close it.

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366854/jquery-ui-dialog-box-close-function)