# jQueryUI, function on window close

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've this function in jQuery:

```
    $("#bottone_mail").on("click", function(){
        $('#container_body').fadeTo(1000, 0.25);
        $( "#form" ).dialog({
            width:510,height:500});
            return false;
```

That creates a form window. When the user clicks the "Send" button, this script is executed:

```
        $("#invia").on("click", function(){
        $( "#form" ).dialog("close");
        $('#container_body').fadeTo(1000, 1);
        $("#spc1").html("<div id='mess_invio'> Messaggio inviato con successo, grazie!</div>");
        return false;
        });
```

I want  `$('#container_body').fadeTo(1000, 1);` to be executed when the user closes the form window with the "X" button, other than when the "Send" button is pressed.

The only related answer I could find is this:
[jQuery UI Dialog Box - does not open after being closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366854/jquery-ui-dialog-box-close-function)

It doesn't work for me, though, as a function name is required.

I'm at my first steps with jQuery, so I'd be very thankful if someone was to post a tailored solution with an explanation...

Comment: it would help if you also show the html for your close button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have options when you create the dialog.

Maybe you can use something like:

```
$( "#form" ).dialog({
        width:510,
        height:500,
        close: function() {
                    $('#container_body').fadeTo(1000, 1);
        }
});
```

Comment: @user2413551 You can accept an answer by pressing the tick ( v ) on the left of it

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this -

```
$("#form").on('dialogclose', function(event) {
   $('#container_body').fadeTo(1000, 1);
});
```

- http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-close