# Call jquery dialog close event explicitily

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a jQuery dialog on my page and for some reason I am using custom HTMl in the `title` option of dialog function which consists of a span as well (acting as `close button` for me):-

```
$("#myDivId").dialog({
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    closeOnEscape: false,
    draggable: false,
    title: "<div><span class='ui-dialog-title'>History</span>
           <a class='ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all'>
          <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-closethick'>X</span></a></div>",
    width: 700,
    height: 300,
    open: function (event, ui) { 
        $('.ui-widget-overlay').css('height', $(window).height()); 
    },
    close: function () { alert(1); }
 });
```

Is there any way to call the `close` event of jQuery dialog on click of my span which consists of `X` text so that I can close the dialog?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366854/jquery-ui-dialog-box-close-function

Comment: seems to be already working as expected https://jsfiddle.net/BeNdErR/bmL779f1/

Comment: Doesn't it already do that by default -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/1x89Lkb8/

Comment: @adeneo, beNdErR - It's not working for me. Can't check fiddle now due to restrictions will check that later and get back.

Answer (score 0):

How about this on your close function:

```
$('#myDivId').dialog('close')
```